# Library or Framework recommendation for dependent entity processing

Tags: java, stream, frameworks, batch-processing

I have a batch of data coming from a service. Data needs to processed in the order of their dependencies on each other. I would like get pointer on the best practices and approach to handle this in Java.

Example:

- Batch of managers (M1,M2...) coming into the system. Simultaneously we also get batch of employees (E1,E2...) and Their addresses (A1,A2..).
- An address can only be processed when the employee that it is linked to has been processed. Similarly an employee can only be processed when manager it is linked to has been processed.
- General order of processing for address A1, employee E1 and manager M1 is as
  M1 -> E1 -> A1

```
               ────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬────┬──────────
                   │     │     │     │     │     │     │     │    │
         xx  xx  xx│ M1  │  M2 │  M3 │  M4 │  M5 │  M6 │  M7 │  M8│   xx xx xx
                   │     │     │     │     │     │     │     │    │
              ─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴────┴───────────

        ─────────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬────┬─────┬────┬────┬────────
                 │      │     │     │    │     │    │    │
        xx  xx xx│  E1  │  E2 │  E3 │ E4 │  E5 │ E6 │ E7 │xx xx xx
                 │      │     │     │    │     │    │    │
        ─────────┴──────┴─────┴─────┴────┴─────┴────┴────┴────────

 ───────┬─────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬──────
        │     │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │
xx xx xx│  A1 │ A2 │ A3 │ A4 │ A5 │ A6 │ A7 │ A7 │ A8 │xx xx xx
        │     │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │
 ───────┴─────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴──────
```

Comment: You should try a Reactive Streams implementation, like RxJava or Spring Reactor...

Comment: Thanks @RafaelGuillen. That's what I have as of now. Was looking to see if there is a better solution / framework etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can (and in almost all cases you can) i would consider ["eventual consistency"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eventual-consistency/info).

And that said i think that:

> Data needs to processed in the order of their dependencies on each other.

Is just not true. You should challenge this statement with your team until it falls (There are very, very rare cases where this is true).

It would make your life much easier if your data just does not depend on each other in the "hard" way.

The way you describe your domain, you must have a connection property (id or something) anyway. So:

- Import Managers, Employees and Addresses whenever they arrive
- In the Moment of observation (whenever the data needs to be accessed) only consider datasets where Managers, Employees and Addresses are available OR
- Write a job that copies datasets from the eventual consitency to a consistent data structur where you just leave out everything that is not yet complete
- If you are very tidy, write a job that empties all dependent structures (Addresses, employees) that to not have a parent entry yet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This would work an ideal use case where you control all the systems that deal with data. It is a difficult proposition when your middleware is using existing APIs internal & external to persist this data. 
Any client for such system has to follow the set process on how it can call to persist the data.